# "NoneType object is not iterable" error while appending JSON data to lists

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape customer reviews data from Shopee by using JSON URL calls. However, I encountered the error - 'NoneType' object is not iterable, while trying to append the retrieved JSON data into lists. I have looked through the related questions here, but could not find the solution.

Below are my codes for retrieval of the customer reviews data:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


def get_ratings(shop_id, item_id):
    ratings_url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get_ratings?filter=0&flag=1&itemid={item_id}&limit=20&offset={offset}&shopid={shop_id}&type=0"

    offset = 0
    d = {"product_id": [], "username": [], "rating": [], "comment": []}
    while True:
        data = requests.get(
            ratings_url.format(shop_id=shop_id, item_id=item_id, offset=offset)
        ).json()

        # uncomment this to print all data:
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

        i = 1
        for i, rating in enumerate(data["data"]["ratings"], 1):
            d["product_id"].append(rating["itemid"])
            d["username"].append(rating["author_username"])
            d["rating"].append(rating["rating_star"])
            d["comment"].append(rating["comment"])

        if i % 20:
            break

        offset += 20

    return d


keyword_search = "Fishball"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Chrome",
    "Referer": "{}search?keyword={}".format(Shopee_url, keyword_search),
}

url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword={}&limit=100&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search".format(
    keyword_search
)
# can change "relevancy" to "latest": to sort by latest products instead

# Shopee API request
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# For Products: Create lists to hold the items
p_product_id = []
p_product_name = []
p_product_price = []
p_product_soldquantity = []
p_product_rating = []

# For Reviews: Create lists to hold the items
r_product_id = []
r_customer_username = []
r_customer_rating = []
r_customer_review = []

# Populate "Products" lists
for item in r["items"]:
    p_product_id.append(item["itemid"])
    p_product_name.append(item["name"])
    p_product_price.append(item["price_min"])
    p_product_soldquantity.append(item["historical_sold"])
    p_product_rating.append(item["item_rating"]["rating_star"])

    
for item in r["items"]:

    review_item = get_ratings(item["shopid"], item["itemid"])
    r_product_id = r_product_id + review_item["product_id"]
    r_customer_username = r_customer_username + review_item["username"]
    r_customer_rating = r_customer_rating + review_item["rating"]
    r_customer_review = r_customer_review + review_item["comment"]
```

Here is a snippet of the error:

[image]

I have to looked at the JSON dump data to figure out the source of the error. Such as:

- Testing if the values of any of the keys(itemid, author_username, rating_star, comment) being null/None or "", are causing the "Nonetype" error. However, it doesn't cause any errors and would successfully append to the lists as I wanted.
- Testing if any of the keys being missing causes the "Nonetype" error. However, it will just result a different error stating that the particular key is not declared.

Edited for @flakes: Below is a sample of the JSON dump. However, the actual dump data is a lot larger. Therefore, the error might not exist in this sample of code:

```
{
    "data": {
        "ratings": [],
        "item_rating_summary": {
            "rating_total": 0,
            "rating_count": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "rcount_with_context": 0,
            "rcount_with_image": 0,
            "rcount_with_media": 0,
            "rcount_local_review": 0,
            "rcount_repeat_purchase": 0
        },
        "is_sip_item": false,
        "rcmd_algo": "ABTEST:2.a.312@AD12"
    },
    "error": 0,
    "error_msg": null
}
{
    "data": {
        "ratings": [
            {
                "orderid": 49169039164703,
                "itemid": 6342546681,
                "cmtid": 2760023244,
                "ctime": 1596074706,
                "rating": 1,
                "userid": 269495210,
                "shopid": 233683003,
                "comment": "Some items didn\u2019t received, and ask for refund on Shopee system, and Shopee ask for return all the items to Shopee(excuse me! Fresh items wow).....This make me crazy. Finally, seller have solved this problem and I got the refund already. Seller also reply slowly. I\u2019m so disappointed with Shopee ",
                "rating_star": 4,
                "status": 1,
                "mtime": 1596074706,
                "editable": 0,
                "opt": 2,
                "filter": 7,
                "mentioned": [],
                "is_hidden": false,
                "author_username": "kgamdr9qx6",
                "author_portrait": "",
                "author_shopid": 269491453,
                "anonymous": false,
                "images": [
                    "a19dfc8f10afe789b586ed934f902adc"
                ],
                "videos": [
                    {
                        "id": "sg_132892ff-a252-4505-ad1b-94ecf8cf4693_000046",
                        "cover": "https://play-ws.vod.shopee.com/c4/98934353/10321063012/YzQsMTI0LTE2NzMyLDE0MTAwODg1NTg2NzI0NDU0NDAsMw.jpg",
                        "url": "https://play-ws.vod.shopee.com/c4/98934353/10321063012/YzQsMTI0LTE2NzMyLDE0MTAwODkwMTc0Nzg5NzEzOTIsMw.mp4",
                        "duration": 7106,
                        "upload_time": null
                    }
                ],
                "product_items": [
                    {
                        "itemid": 6342546681,
                        "shopid": 233683003,
                        "name": "BoBo Cooked Fishball 500g",
                        "image": "55156d13a9cda32c12d9a170196b219a",
                        "is_snapshot": 1,
                        "snapshotid": 1957356912,
                        "modelid": 40318347777,
                        "model_name": ""
                    }
                ],
                "delete_reason": null,
                "delete_operator": null,
                "ItemRatingReply": null,
                "tags": null,
                "editable_date": null,
                "show_reply": null,
                "like_count": null,
                "liked": null,
                "sync_to_social": false,
                "detailed_rating": null,
                "exclude_scoring_due_low_logistic": false,
                "loyalty_info": null,
                "template_tags": [],
                "has_template_tag": false,
                "sync_to_social_toggle": null,
                "sip_info": {
                    "is_oversea": false,
                    "origin_region": "sg"
                },
                "is_repeated_purchase": false
            },
            {
                "orderid": 76164426633592,
                "itemid": 6342546681,
                "cmtid": 4977003708,
                "ctime": 1622799587,
                "rating": 1,
                "userid": 193560584,
                "shopid": 233683003,
                "comment": "",
                "rating_star": 5,
                "status": 1,
                "mtime": 1622799587,
                "editable": 0,
                "opt": 2,
                "filter": 0,
                "mentioned": [],
                "is_hidden": false,
                "author_username": "fynahros",
                "author_portrait": "",
                "author_shopid": 193557725,
                "anonymous": false,
                "images": null,
                "videos": [],
                "product_items": [
                    {
                        "itemid": 6342546681,
                        "shopid": 233683003,
                        "name": "BoBo Cooked Fishball 500g",
                        "image": "11e161f9dbea1be563bff914beedfed8",
                        "is_snapshot": 1,
                        "snapshotid": 2373175027,
                        "modelid": 40318347777,
                        "model_name": ""
                    }
                ],
                "delete_reason": null,
                "delete_operator": null,
                "ItemRatingReply": null,
                "tags": null,
                "editable_date": null,
                "show_reply": null,
                "like_count": null,
                "liked": null,
                "sync_to_social": false,
                "detailed_rating": null,
                "exclude_scoring_due_low_logistic": false,
                "loyalty_info": null,
                "template_tags": [],
                "has_template_tag": false,
                "sync_to_social_toggle": null,
                "sip_info": {
                    "is_oversea": false,
                    "origin_region": "sg"
                },
                "is_repeated_purchase": false
            },
            {
                "orderid": 50027730227101,
                "itemid": 6342546681,
                "cmtid": 2779109484,
                "ctime": 1596443125,
                "rating": 1,
                "userid": 67658682,
                "shopid": 233683003,
                "comment": "",
                "rating_star": 5,
                "status": 1,
                "mtime": 1596443125,
                "editable": 0,
                "opt": 2,
                "filter": 0,
                "mentioned": [],
                "is_hidden": false,
                "author_username": "lynn1967",
                "author_portrait": "",
                "author_shopid": 67657225,
                "anonymous": false,
                "images": null,
                "videos": [],
                "product_items": [
                    {
                        "itemid": 6342546681,
                        "shopid": 233683003,
                        "name": "BoBo Cooked Fishball 500g",
                        "image": "55156d13a9cda32c12d9a170196b219a",
                        "is_snapshot": 1,
                        "snapshotid": 1957356912,
                        "modelid": 40318347777,
                        "model_name": ""
                    }
                ],
                "delete_reason": null,
                "delete_operator": null,
                "ItemRatingReply": null,
                "tags": null,
                "editable_date": null,
                "show_reply": null,
                "like_count": null,
                "liked": null,
                "sync_to_social": false,
                "detailed_rating": null,
                "exclude_scoring_due_low_logistic": false,
                "loyalty_info": null,
                "template_tags": [],
                "has_template_tag": false,
                "sync_to_social_toggle": null,
                "sip_info": {
                    "is_oversea": false,
                    "origin_region": "sg"
                },
                "is_repeated_purchase": false
            }
        ],
        "item_rating_summary": {
            "rating_total": 17,
            "rating_count": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                1,
                16
            ],
            "rcount_with_context": 11,
            "rcount_with_image": 11,
            "rcount_with_media": 11,
            "rcount_local_review": 0,
            "rcount_repeat_purchase": 0
        },
        "is_sip_item": false,
        "rcmd_algo": "ABTEST:2.a.312@AD12"
    },
    "error": 0,
    "error_msg": null
}
```

Edited for @tdelaney: I found out that the key "rating" in the last dictionary has a "null" value:

```
{
    "data": {
        "ratings": null,
        "item_rating_summary": {
            "rating_total": 0,
            "rating_count": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "rcount_with_context": 0,
            "rcount_with_image": 0,
            "rcount_with_media": 0,
            "rcount_local_review": 0,
            "rcount_repeat_purchase": 0
        },
        "is_sip_item": false,
        "rcmd_algo": "ABTEST:2.a.312@AD12"
    },
    "error": 0,
    "error_msg": null
}
```

Comment: The error means that `data['data']['ratings']` is `None`, not a list.

Comment: "I wanted to paste a sample of the JSON dump, but is unable to, as a reasonable sample will still be too long to be pasted here." You can always remove parts of the json to show us the general structure. It's not going to be possible to diagnose the issue accurately without it.

Comment: The thing that jumps out immediately is that there is no test for errors after the get. Check the statuscode. Just before the `for`, `print(type(data)); print(type(data["data"])); print(type(data["data"]["ratings"]))`. See what's NoneType and what raises the error.

Comment: You could open the json in a text editor and search for `null`.

Comment: Could you provide one valid URI (including `item_id`, `offset` and `shop_id`) so that one can see the json returned?

Comment: @flakes Got it, I should've provided a sample of the JSON data regardless. Edited the post and included it, thanks!

Comment: @marcel h 
A sample can be - item_id: 6342546681 , offset: 0, shop_id: 233683003

More sample can be taken from the edited post above, thanks :)

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks! I found out that the very last "ratings" list is indeed null. Finding a way to work around it now.